# How to combine pytube and tkinter label to show progress?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pytube

I am writing small program which downloads song from youtube (using pytube)
and I want to add python tkinter GUI to show percent value when the file is downloading.

Now when I execute my code, program at first downloads the file (takes about 60sec) and only then shows the label with 100%. What should I change in my code if I want to see label value climbing from 0% to 100% at the same time when the file is been downloaded?

Code Python3:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# main application shows:
# label Loading..
# label which configure values when file is downloading 
# inderterminate progress bar
class MainApplication(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master = master

    self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
    self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.youtubeEntry = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVy9Lgpg1m8"
    self.FolderLoacation = "C:/Users/Jonis/Desktop/"

    # pytube
    self.yt = YouTube(self.youtubeEntry)

    video_type = self.yt.streams.filter(only_audio = True).first()

    # file size of a file
    self.MaxfileSize = video_type.filesize

    # Loading label
    self.loadingLabel = ttk.Label(self.master, text="Loading...", font=("Agency FB", 30))
    self.loadingLabel.grid(pady=(100,0))

    # loading precent label which must show % donwloaded
    self.loadingPercent = tk.Label(self.master, text="", fg="green", font=("Agency FB", 30))
    self.loadingPercent.grid(pady=(30,30))

    # indeterminate progress bar
    self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.master, orient="horizontal", length=500, mode='indeterminate')
    self.progressbar.grid(pady=(50,0))
    self.progressbar.start()    

    # call Download file func
    self.DownloadFile


def DownloadFile(self):
    self.yt.register_on_progress_callback(self.show_progress_bar)
    self.yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(self.FolderLoacation)

# func count precent of a file
def show_progress_bar(self, stream=None, chunk=None, file_handle=None, bytes_remaining=None):

    # loadingPercent label configure value %
    self.loadingPercent.config(text=str(100 - (100*(bytes_remaining/self.MaxfileSize))))


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Youtube downloader")
root.geometry("1920x1080")
app = MainApplication(root)
root.mainloop()`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue which appears to be is that you need to call `self.DownloadFile` and `self.show_progress_ba`r at the same time as you mentioned. To call both functions at the same time the best solution is to use thread library

```
from pytube import YouTube
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading


# main application shows:
# label Loading..
# label which configure values when file is downloading 
# inderterminate progress bar
class MainApplication(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master = master

    self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
    self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.youtubeEntry = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVy9Lgpg1m8"
    self.FolderLoacation = "C:/Users/Jonis/Desktop/"

    # pytube
    self.yt = YouTube(self.youtubeEntry)

    video_type = self.yt.streams.filter(only_audio = True).first()

    # file size of a file
    self.MaxfileSize = video_type.filesize

    # Loading label
    self.loadingLabel = ttk.Label(self.master, text="Loading...", font=("Agency FB", 30))
    self.loadingLabel.grid(pady=(100,0))

    # loading precent label which must show % donwloaded
    self.loadingPercent = tk.Label(self.master, text="0", fg="green", font=("Agency FB", 30))
    self.loadingPercent.grid(pady=(30,30))

    # indeterminate progress bar
    self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.master, orient="horizontal", length=500, mode='indeterminate')
    self.progressbar.grid(pady=(50,0))
    self.progressbar.start()    

    threading.Thread(target=self.yt.register_on_progress_callback(self.show_progress_bar)).start()

    # call Download file func
    threading.Thread(target=self.DownloadFile).start()



def DownloadFile(self):


    self.yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(self.FolderLoacation)

# func count precent of a file
def show_progress_bar(self, stream=None, chunk=None, file_handle=None, bytes_remaining=None):

    # loadingPercent label configure value %
    self.loadingPercent.config(text=str(int(100 - (100*(bytes_remaining/self.MaxfileSize)))))


root = tk.Tk() 
root.title("Youtube downloader")
root.geometry("1920x1080")
app = MainApplication(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Counting didn't always start here at 100

Comment: It outputs an error: `percent = (100 * (fileSizeInBytes - remaining)) / fileSizeInBytes
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'`